# Plotting CSV file with gnuplot returning line 0: x range is invalid

Tags: csv, gnuplot

My CSV file looks like this:

```
Sections,Score
text,5.80653548846
rdata,3.96936179484
data,0.378703493488
pdata,1.97732827586
rsrc,2.81352566021
reloc,0.46347168954
```

I'm running the command:

`gnuplot -p -e "set datafile separator ','; plot '/temp_files/iMiHRlrcQLwWYXjbjmTydBITw_PlotGraph.csv' using 1:2 with lines;"`

And I'm getting the error:

```
line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

set datafile separator ','; plot '/temp_files/iMiHRlrcQLwWYXjbjmTydBITw_PlotGraph.csv' using 1:2 with lines;
                                                                                                                                                ^
line 0: x range is invalid
```

I've tried the following:

- Editing the CSV file to not contain the `Sections,Score` part.
- Setting the ylabel and xlabel with `set xlabel "Sections"; set ylabel "Scores";`
- Running `set title "Entropy"; set grid; plot "FILENAME"; using 0:1 with lines`
- Using the suggestions from these posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209651/plotting-data-from-dat-file-and-csv-file-on-a-same-graph-using-gnu-plot), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349185/how-to-scatterplot-data-from-csv-file-in-gnuplot), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70774684/bashscript-with-gnuplot-on-csv-file), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281139/generate-a-graph-from-csv-using-gnuplot)

However, regardless of the research I'm still expecting gnuplot to accept the CSV file and return a plotted graph, how can I turn the CSV presented into a graph using gnuplot successfully?

An example of what I would want would be something along the lines of:

```
    8
    7
 S  6
 C  5
 O  4
 R  3 |\        ___
 E  2 | \      /
    1 |  \____/
    0 |  
     text rdata data
         Sections
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ethan already mentioned, you need a x-coordinate.
In your modified question you specify that the text in column 1 should be on the x-axis.
In this case you can use the pseudocolumn 0 (which is basically the row index, starting from 0) as x-value and add the text via `xticlabels()`. Check `help pseudocolumns` and `help xticlabels`.
For this type of plot you might want to use the plotting style `with boxes` or as you intended `with lines`.

In short, something like: `plot "myData.dat" u 0:2:xtic(1) w lines`, or as a full script...

**Script:**

```
### plot "text" data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Sections,Score
text,5.80653548846
rdata,3.96936179484
data,0.378703493488
pdata,1.97732827586
rsrc,2.81352566021
reloc,0.46347168954
EOD

set datafile separator comma
set style fill solid 0.3
set boxwidth 0.8
set xtics out nomirror
set grid y
set xlabel "Sections"
set ylabel "Score"
set key noautotitle

plot $Data u 0:2:xtic(1) w boxes, \
        '' u 0:2 w linespoints pt 7
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Column 1 of your data file contains text rather than numbers.  You cannot use this column as either an x or a y coordinate.  Thus both `plot ... using 1:2` and `plot ... using 0:1` will fail because the program finds no [x,y] coordinate pair on any line of the file.  That is what the error message `"no valid points"` is trying to tell you.

What coordinates do you want on the x and y axes of your graph? If column 2 is y, what is x?

Comment: Do the edits help to better understand what I'm asking?